# Laravel Undefined property

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to access the roleplay relationship in a foreach player in laravel but its just throwing a Undefined property error at me every time, can someone help me out?

My code is fine untill it hits the @if involving ->roleplay

```
@foreach ($players as $key => $player)
    <tr id="tr_player_{{ $player->id }}">
        <td>{{ $player->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->username }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->mail }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->ip_last }}</td>
        <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($player->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</td>
        <td>
            @if ($player->roleplay->current_working == '1')
                    Working
                @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_jailed == '1')
                    Jailed
                @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_dead == '1')
                    Dead
                @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_wanted == '1')
                    Wanted
                @else
                    Alive
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Player class:

```
use Hash;
use Eloquent;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authentication;

class Player extends Eloquent implements Authentication
{
    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    protected $table        = 'users';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['username'] = $value;
    }

    public function roleplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Roleplay class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Website\User;

use Eloquent;

class Roleplay extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'user_id';
    protected $table        = 'srp_user_statistics';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Website\User\Player', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function government_role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Website\Roleplay\GovernmentRole', 'government_id');
    }
}
```

How did I get the $players collection?

```
$players = Player::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Here are the results of my dd method

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => array:44 [▶]
  1 => array:44 [▶]
  2 => array:44 [▶]
  3 => array:44 [▶]
  4 => array:44 [▶]
  5 => array:44 [▶]
  6 => array:44 [▶]
  7 => array:44 [▶]
  8 => array:44 [▶]
  9 => array:44 [▶]
  10 => array:44 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "username" => "Liam Savage"
    "password" => "$2y$10$axynRJSDIRnRch5w5CjcV.3pTdAprjKOZNri0vniRANXPce/74DFK"
    "mail" => "liamsavage619@gmail.com"
    "last_change" => 0
    "machine_id" => "~203c89fda517afe6d0e99494e00fe7b6"
    "updated_at" => "2016-11-14 00:30:36"
    "created_at" => "2016-07-25 03:45:44"
    "remember_token" => "hG1QZE3fPQphjPhcWeZ4ifeZYiKbJBvPIZKSL8xXkuJPXh4ukrodfMRjyvn0"
    "last_admin_login" => "Mon, Jan 30, 2017 11:43 AM"
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you post the line where the error throws

Comment: I did, "My code is fine untill it hits the @if involving ->roleplay" it starts when I do my first ATif the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get that error when a player in the `$players` collection doesn't have a roleplay.  If you only want to load players with roleplays you can update your players query to:

```
$players = Player::has('roleplay')->with('roleplay')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

If you want to load all then you need to update your blade view to check for the existence of a roleplay before accessing it like @aimme said in his answer.

Either way you should definitely be lazy loading that relationship.  The way you originally have it, you are running into the N+1 issue in your view and running a new query for every player to retrieve their roleplay. To just lazy load the roleplays update your query to:

```
$players = Player::with('roleplay')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: That's the point I am trying to get across is every player has a role play, when using the "$players = Player::with('roleplay')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();" query it still loads all 11 players it previously loaded but still throws the same error when I add the @if endif stuff.

Comment: After running the query, what is the output of `dd($players->pluck('roleplay'));`?

Comment: You forgot the `has('roleplay')` portion which is the part which actually limits to players that have a roleplayrelation in your query.

Comment: I tried with that also and it still resulted in the same result.

Comment: You stated there were 11 players being returned but in your `$players->pluck('roleplay');` there are only 10 roleplays being returned.  One player doesn't have one assigned.  If you want to find out which one then you can do `dd($players->reject(function($player) { return $player->roleplay; })->first());` which will give you the player who doesn't have a roleplay assigned.  To avoid this use the `has('roleplay')` in your query like:  `Player::with('roleplay')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to access a property of $player->roleplay while there is not ->roleplay . so the $player->roleplay will be null, and you are checking on null. check whether it exists before trying to accessing to the properties of it.

```
@if($player->roleplay)    
 @if ($player->roleplay->current_working == '1')
    Working
 @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_jailed == '1')
    Jailed
 @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_dead == '1')
     Dead
 @elseif ($player->roleplay->currently_wanted == '1')
     Wanted
 @else
     Alive
 @endif
@endif
```

and also you could do something like this

```
@foreach ($players as $player)
```

instead of this

```
@foreach ($players as $key => $player)
```

Comment: But I know that it exists as it works in other parts of my code, just not in view?

Comment: it would sometimes exist and sometimes it might not exist. and as its a foreach loop in every loop object it must exist, else you need to handle it like so.  just do a dd($players->toArray()); and show me the output

Comment: I get this: array:11 [▼
  0 => array:44 [▶]
  1 => array:44 [▶]
  2 => array:44 [▶]
  3 => array:44 [▶]
  4 => array:44 [▶]
  5 => array:44 [▶]
  6 => array:44 [▶]
  7 => array:44 [▶]
  8 => array:44 [▶]
  9 => array:44 [▶]
  10 => array:44 [▶]
]

Comment: brow can you expend those arrows and post it in the question. i mean update the question with tht dump included?

Comment: I have edited my question, I didn't expand all of them but their all the exact same with so I just expanded one.

Comment: @Ashkru  One `$player->roleplay`  is null